# How to create an aliase email address for all of our registered users to communicate without disclosing their real email address

Tags: php, email

I have witnessed a few websites that hide the registered users real email address from eachother but I have never understood how this works.

Lets take Gumtree as an example. user A browses gumtree and finds something they want to buy, one option is to contact the seller by email, they email user B but when the email is received by user B, the email address address is sfsdgewfssf.fsf@gumtree.com, when user B replies to sfsdgewfssf.fsf@gumtree.com it is delivered in Users A's real email inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when a user creates an account at a site like this, an anonymous-ish email address is created for them and this email address is stored in their user record.  Any email from one user to another is sent to the created anonymous email address which is autoforwarded to their real email address the user entered when they created the account.

Comment: Thank you, I am try to search for some possible repositories but I am lost for keywords. Git hub could potentially have a solution. Could you reocmmend some key words?